# What are the differences between "Escape" and a common task to get free?

Tags: cypher-system

The Explorer special ability **Escape** (2 Speed point), as stated in the (old) Cypher System Rulebook is used to get free (p. 41):

> You slip your
>   restraints, squeeze through the bars, break the
>   grip of a creature holding you, pull free from
>   sucking quicksand, or otherwise get loose
>   from whatever is holding you in place. Action.

But this is already possible using a common Might or Speed (or even Intellect) task, as stated in example in the description of the Giant (p. 295):

> If a giant attacks a single target, she can choose to do regular damage or to grab hold of
>   her victim, dealing 4 points of damage instead. On his turn, **the victim can attempt a
>   Might defense roll to struggle out of the grip, a Speed defense roll to slip out, or an
>   Intellect-based task to distract the giant**.

So what's the difference between Escape and a common defense roll?

Comment: Isn't the giant related escape action linked to the giants ability to grab and not a generic action?

Comment: @Litany I wrote "as stated **in example** in the description of the Giant" because there is no specific rule to break free (even if for the _Deinonychus_ is very similar), but it is safe to say that is a standard Might or Speed action. If you have futher details please improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

*As written*, I don't see a difference: a PC could break free using **Escape** or a regular Might/Speed/Intellect task.

However, I can think of a few differences:

- As you stated, breaking free might be a Might, Speed or even Intellect task, depending on the context, how the action is narrated, etc. **Escape**, on the other hand, is a Speed task, no matter the context, meaning this could make the action more reliably easier for a character built on Speed.
- Narratively speaking, escaping from most situations would take some time. Wikiepedia, for instance, states that the world record for escaping a straitjacket is 8.4 seconds - and that's from a highly specialized indidivual. As a GM, I would assume that a character escaping a straitjacket or even simple handcuffs would require much more time. In the case of **Escape**, it is an ability of type *Action*, meaning it would require a simple combat action (ie. about 6 seconds) to escape whatever is holding its user - that's even faster than the world record! In a time-sensitive situation, this could be a life saver.

Comment: As you explained it, basically Escape let the player set the task to be a Speed task and let the character to be free in an Action instead of a minute. This answer sound more balanced than others, but it's hard to narrate how a characted get free of a mind restraint with a speed task.

Comment: Agreed, but RAW, clearly, the ability text does not mention anything about narrative plausibility being a requirement for its use. Whether a GM would allow that or not is up to them and their group.

Answer (score 0):

### *Escape* doesn't let you do something new, it lets you do it better.

A player can normally attempt a task to get free of something. You are able to spend speed/might/intellect points to improve the odds of success, and failure may mean damage.

*Escape* costs 2 speed points, but there is no task to attempt. The player escapes automatically with no task. There is no chance of failure (unless there is a GM intrusion coming!), and no chance of taking damage. All of this makes *Escape* far safer than a task.

The question explicitly contrasts *Escape* to defense tasks.  But *Escape* also applies to non-combat situations. For example, a character tied up and left in a room could use the *Escape* ability to get out of the restraints. No kind of defense task will help you (though you could use a Speed/Might/Intellect task to attempt to escape anyway).

This is how I adjudicate abilities in Numenera. If an ability says you do something, you do it so long as it is allowed by the fiction.

### This isn't all that powerful in most circumstances

In a comment, you mentioned that this seems powerful. Does it mean that a character can spend 2 speed to overcome a difficulty 9 challenge?

No. A difficulty 9 challenge is impossible. Unless you bring down the difficulty level, it may not be overcome by any means. In a logical sense this is an "unstoppable force meets immovable object" kind of problem. I would recommend leading with the fiction to adjudicate what happens.

Is this ability overly powerful for tasks that aren't impossible? The highest "possible" difficulty is 6. A fresh tier 1 character would have to be fairly invested to have decent odds at this, unless they have access to some assets to help.

On the other hand, *Escape* comes at a high opportunity costs. Abilities aren't plentiful, and choosing *Escape* means foregoing many others. It provides a significant bonus for a number of relatively uncommon situations. At higher tiers where the player is likely to have a higher effort score and speed edge, it's usefulness will be diluted.

Comment: So to break free from a restraining crypto level 9 require a Speed task with difficulty 9, but a character with Escape can just spend 2 Intellect points and get free? Isn't it too overpowered?

Comment: @Ohmnibus Edited in response to your comment. Short answer - you can't use Escape to pass a difficulty 9 task, because those tasks are impossible. The benefits are good, but not overly powerful in most other circumstances. Your mileage may vary.